# Failure to load model in tensorflow.js

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I have converted different transfer trained models (VGG16, InceptionV3, EfficientNetB0) from tensorflow in python to tensorflowjs.
And after implementing into tensorflowjs, it fails to load the model.

One of the error is:

```
Uncaught Error: Unknown layer: Functional. This may be due to one of the following reasons:
1. The layer is defined in Python, in which case it needs to be ported to TensorFlow.js or your JavaScript code.
2. The custom layer is defined in JavaScript, but is not registered properly with tf.serialization.registerClass().
    at jN (generic_utils.js:242)
    at GI (serialization.js:31)
    at e.fromConfig (models.js:1026)
    at jN (generic_utils.js:277)
    at GI (serialization.js:31)
    at models.js:295
    at u (runtime.js:45)
    at Generator._invoke (runtime.js:274)
    at Generator.forEach.t.<computed> [as next] (runtime.js:97)
    at Wm (runtime.js:728)
```

Also, there is

```
jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Unknown layer: RandomFlip. This may be due to one of the following reasons:
1. The layer is defined in Python, in which case it needs to be ported to TensorFlow.js or your JavaScript code.
2. The custom layer is defined in JavaScript, but is not registered properly with tf.serialization.registerClass().
    at jN (generic_utils.js:242)
    at GI (serialization.js:31)
    at e.fromConfig (models.js:1026)
    at jN (generic_utils.js:277)
    at GI (serialization.js:31)
    at e.fromConfig (models.js:1026)
    at jN (generic_utils.js:277)
    at GI (serialization.js:31)
    at models.js:295
    at u (runtime.js:45)
```

Also,

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
```

What is the problem?
If I use the .json file generated from teachable machine, the model can be loaded. (However, the predictions become completely wrong for unknown reasons, and the problems seems to be more than just labelling issue.)
But if I use model.json file generated from .h5 or SavedModel via tensorflow converter, no matter which pretrained models I use, or the file formats (.h5 or SavedModel) to generate, the model cannot be loaded into the javascript.

Please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the `model.json` file and search for the keyword `Functional`(you could use `ctrl+f Functional`) and replace the word with `Model`.

Comment: How about the Unknown layer: RandomFlip ?
This seems to be due to augmentation layer not recognized by tensorflow.js.
I have incorporated the data augmentation layer as one of the model layer, following the tutorials from tensorflow official website.
How should I deal with this problem?

Comment: @Maximus you will have to ask another question for that. I will try to answer it as well. Could you accept and upvote my question as it solves your problem?

Comment: Thanks! Accepted and upvoted your question. I have asked another question in the following links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66616597/tensorflow-js-error-in-loading-augmentation-layers-operation