# Uncaught (in promise) Error: Unknown layer:

Tags: python, reactjs, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I'm developing a plants disease classification app using React and tensorflow.
To fill this job, I have developed an AI model with CNN and preprocessing layers.
the model works fine on google colab, but when I converted it to the JSON form to deploy it in my app it shows me this error on my browsers console:

```
 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Unknown layer: RandomFlip. This may be due to one of the following reasons:
```

1. The layer is defined in Python, in which case it needs to be ported to TensorFlow.js or your JavaScript code.
2. The custom layer is defined in JavaScript, but is not registered properly with tf.serialization.registerClass().

this is my python code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""Copie de Untitled7.ipynb

Automatically generated by Colaboratory.

Original file is located at
    https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1IFoiRxZ-FLnM-SIc6YfMtVooH2s-cMP4
"""

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

import zipfile
import os
zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile('/content/drive/MyDrive/SoniaKarimDatasetPFA_Agriculture/archive.zip','r')
zip_ref.extractall('/content')
zip_ref.close()

len(os.listdir('/content'))



#importing necessary directories for analysis
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import models, layers, callbacks
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

!pip install split-folders

#Some additional parameters
#It is a good practice to declare these parameters 
#outside of the functions also in a separate code block
directory = '/content/PlantVillage'
IMAGE_SIZE = 258
BATCH_SIZE = 32
CHANNELS = 3
EPOCHS = 3

import splitfolders
splitfolders.ratio(directory, output="output",
    seed=1337, ratio=(.7,.3), group_prefix=None, move=False)

#Now, we gonna do the do! time to deal with 
#our images!
#Let's call this tensorflow.keras function which will
#... you know!
dataset = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    "/content/output/val", 
    shuffle = True,
    image_size = (IMAGE_SIZE,IMAGE_SIZE ),
    batch_size = BATCH_SIZE
)

#dataset = dataset.take(int(len(dataset)*0.35))

class_names = dataset.class_names
class_names

len(dataset)

plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
for image_batch, label_batch in dataset.take(1):
  for i in range(12):
    ax = plt.subplot(3,4,i+1)
    plt.imshow(image_batch[i].numpy().astype('uint8'))
    plt.title(class_names[label_batch[i]])
    plt.axis('off')
    #print(image_batch[0].shape)
    #print(label_batch.numpy())



train_size = int(len(dataset)*0.8)
train_size

train_ds = dataset.take(train_size)
test_ds = dataset.skip(train_size)

validation_size = int(len(dataset)*0.1)

validation_ds = test_ds.take(validation_size)
test_ds = test_ds.skip(validation_size)

def get_dataset_partitions_tf(ds, train_split = 0.8,
                              val_split = 0.2,
                              test_split = 0.1,
                              shuffle = True,
                              shuffle_size = 10000):
  ds_size = len(ds)

  if shuffle:
    ds = ds.shuffle(shuffle_size, seed = 12)

  train_size = int(train_split * ds_size)
  val_size = int (val_split * ds_size)
  val_ds = ds.skip(train_size).take(val_size)
  train_ds = ds.take(train_size)
  test_ds = ds.skip(train_size).take(val_size)

  return train_ds, val_ds, test_ds

train_ds, val_ds, test_ds = get_dataset_partitions_tf(dataset)

train_ds = train_ds.cache().shuffle(1000).prefetch(buffer_size = tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
val_ds = val_ds.cache().shuffle(1000).prefetch(buffer_size = tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
test_ds = test_ds.cache().shuffle(1000).prefetch(buffer_size = tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

data_augmentation = tf.keras.Sequential([
                     layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomFlip('horizontal_and_vertical'),
                     layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomRotation(0.2)
])

resize_and_rescale = tf.keras.Sequential([
                     layers.experimental.preprocessing.Resizing(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE),
                     layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1.0/255)
])



input_shape = (BATCH_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, CHANNELS)
n_classes = 15

model = models.Sequential([
        resize_and_rescale,
        data_augmentation,
        layers.Conv2D(32 , (3,3), input_shape = input_shape, activation='relu'),
        layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
        layers.Conv2D(64 , (3,3), activation='relu'),
        layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
        layers.Conv2D(64 , (3,3),  activation='relu'),
        layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
        layers.Conv2D(64 , (3,3), activation='relu'),
        layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
        layers.Conv2D(64 , (3,3), activation='relu'),
        layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
        layers.Conv2D(64 , (3,3), activation='relu'),
        layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
        layers.Flatten(),
        layers.Dense(64, activation = 'relu'),
        layers.Dense(n_classes, activation = 'softmax')
])

model.build(input_shape = input_shape )

model.summary()

from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping

early_stopping = EarlyStopping(
    min_delta = 0.001,
    patience = 10,
    restore_best_weights = True,
)

model.compile(
    optimizer =  'adam',
    loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits = False),
    metrics = ['accuracy']
)

from tensorflow.keras import callbacks
history = model.fit(
    train_ds,
    epochs = EPOCHS,
    batch_size = BATCH_SIZE,
    verbose = 1,
    callbacks = [early_stopping],
    validation_data = val_ds
)

score = model.evaluate(test_ds)

score

history.params

history.history.keys()

len(history.history['accuracy'])

acc = history.history['accuracy']
val_acc = history.history['val_accuracy']

loss = history.history['loss']
val_loss = history.history['val_loss']

plt.figure(figsize = (8,8))
plt.subplot(1,2,1)
plt.plot(range(EPOCHS), acc, label = 'Training Accuracy')
plt.plot(range(EPOCHS), val_acc, label = 'Validation Accuracy')
plt.legend(loc = 'lower right')
plt.title('Training and validation Accuracy')

plt.subplot(1,2,2)
plt.plot(range(EPOCHS), loss, label = 'Training_Loss')
plt.plot(range(EPOCHS), val_loss, label = 'Validation Loss')
plt.legend(loc = 'lower right')
plt.title('Training and validation Loss')

for images_batch, labels_batch in test_ds.take(1):
  first_image = (image_batch[0].numpy().astype('uint8'))
  first_label = labels_batch[0]

  print('first image to predict')
  plt.imshow(first_image)
  print('actual label: ', class_names[first_label])

  batch_prediction = model.predict(images_batch)
  print(class_names[np.argmax(batch_prediction[0])])

def predict(model,img):
  img_array = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(images[i].numpy())
  img_array = tf.expand_dims(img_array, 0)

  predictions = model.predict(img_array)

  predicted_class = class_names[np.argmax(predictions[0])]
  confidence = round(100* (np.max(predictions[0])),2)
  return predicted_class, confidence

plt.figure(figsize = (15,15))
for images, labels in test_ds.take(1):
  for i in range (9):
    ax = plt.subplot(3,3,i+1)
    plt.imshow(images[i].numpy().astype('uint8'))

    predicted_class, confidence = predict( model, images[i].numpy())
    actual_class = class_names[labels[i]]
    plt.title(f"actual: {actual_class}, \n Predicted : {predicted_class}  \n Confidence: {confidence} ")
    plt.axis('off')

!pip install tensorflowjs
    import tensorflowjs as tfjs
    tfjs.converters.save_keras_model(model, "mode.h5")
#model.save("model1.h5")

#!pip install tensorflowjs
!tensorflowjs_converter --input_format keras '/content/mode.h5' '/content/sabetna-model'
```

Comment: Found a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66626757/14290697), let us know if this helped. Thanks!